# Access date format issue

Tags: vba, date, ms-access, format

I'm having an issues with some data I'm pulling in Access from a DB2 database.  I   The query works fine and creates the table in access for export to Excel.  However, my dates show up as a 7 digit date 1181108 and when exported to Excel the format show up '181108.  I've tried everything I know to change the format of the date in Access so it will export properly but I'm at a loss.  Changing it from text to a short date only gives me a weird date like in the 9/1/5133.  I know I'm missing something here.  I'm pretty new at VBA and Access and would appreciate a nudge in the right direction on this.  Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Let me edit my question by adding my SQL statement: Below is my query.  Not sure where to insert the date format part. 
'SQL 'statment tp drop data in table

```
 rs.Open "SELECT ITEMBL.HOUSE, SLQNTY.LLOCN, ITMRVA.ITNBR, ITMRVA.ITDSC, SLQNTY.LQNTY, ITEMBL.MOHTQ, ITMRVA.ITCLS,ITEMBL.PLANIB,ITMRVA.ITTYP,SLQNTY.FDATE, ITEMBL.SCPDT,ITMRVA.UCDEF " _
         & " FROM AMFLIBG.ITEMBL ITEMBL, AMFLIBG.ITMRVA ITMRVA, AMFLIBG.ITMRVB ITMRVB, AMFLIBG.SLQNTY SLQNTY " _
         & " WHERE SLQNTY.HOUSE = ITEMBL.HOUSE And SLQNTY.ITNBR = ITEMBL.ITNBR And ITMRVB.ITNBR = ITMRVA.ITNBR And ITMRVB.ITRV = ITMRVA.ITRV And ITMRVB.STID = ITMRVA.STID " _
         & " AND SLQNTY.ITNBR = ITMRVA.ITNBR AND ((ITEMBL.HOUSE='CYP') AND (ITMRVA.STID='003') AND (ITMRVA.CFST='CUR') AND (SLQNTY.LLOCN ='ADJUST'))", CYP_AdjConn



'Loop through IBM data and for each record found, add it to the local table
Do Until rs.EOF
    rsLocal.AddNew
        rsLocal("Whs") = rs("HOUSE")
        rsLocal("Location") = rs("LLOCN")
        rsLocal("Item") = rs("ITNBR")
        rsLocal("Description") = rs("ITDSC")
        rsLocal("On-Hand") = rs("MOHTQ")
        rsLocal("On-Hand2") = rs("LQNTY")
        rsLocal("Default Cost") = rs("UCDEF")
        rsLocal("Class") = rs("ITCLS")
        rsLocal("Planner") = rs("PLANIB")
        rsLocal("I/T") = rs("ITTYP")
        rsLocal("FIFO") = rs("FDATE")
        rsLocal("Date of last scrap") = rs("SCPDT")
    rsLocal.Update
rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like text dates. Convert these (in a query) to true date values before attempting to export to Excel, by stripping the leading 1:

```
TrueDate: DateSerial(Mid([TextField], 2, 2), Mid([TextField], 4, 2), Mid([TextField], 6, 2))
```

"1181108" -> 2018-11-08

If the field is "SCSDT" and "Date of last scrap" is of data type Date, it could be:

```
If Val(rs("SCPDT")) = 0 Then
    rsLocal("Date of last scrap") = Null
Else
    rsLocal("Date of last scrap") = DateSerial(Mid(rs("SCPDT"), 2, 2), Mid(rs("SCPDT"), 4, 2), Mid(rs("SCPDT"), 6, 2))
```

Comment: Would this be a separate query from the one that pulls the data?  Or added to the existing query.  If added. I'm not sure where I would place that statement.

Comment: Existing query should work. Use query designer and input that expression on field row of design grid.

Comment: @Gustav   Thanks we are getting closer.   the date format is correct however, the date is not.  "181108" now looks like  1/3/1931.  I believe there might need to be some trimming of characters.  1180710 needs to be 07/10/2018 .. so I think I need to trim the first number 1 from the text format and tweak the date so that the month and date appear first and then the year.  I misquoted the original text date format it should have had 7 digits instead of 6 .. so 181108 is 1181108 in my  table.  Sorry for the slip up.

Comment: This actually works for the FDATE when I tweak your code for that field. 
 For the SCPDT date it gives me am error message:   'run-time error 13 Type Mismatch'.  (Sigh).   But what it happening is some dates are just a "0" meaning there is not date .  I did not notice this at first in that column.  Anyway to get rid of the "0" or ignore.   Many thanks.

Comment: I've edited the answer to set _Null_ for values of zero.

Comment: @Gustav  Thank you for your assistance.  This worked perfectly.